# How to set layout on custom navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

i want to implement a custom layout like a navigation drawer, same behavior.
I can't do that because a Navigation Drawer use a Menu with items and i need a personalized layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DrawerLayout` as your rootview. It needs to have 2 child views:

- The first is the main layout under the drawer
- The second is the drawer itself. It could be any view what you want.

Example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You can substitute the `ListView` with your personalized layout.

Comment: The second child may need to be `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` but you can add a list view as a child view of the NavigationView.